# How should I test an MVC web app in a container with nunit?

Tags: model-view-controller, nunit, autofac

We have an MVC web which is running in Autofac.  All the config is stored in an autofac config section in the web.config and when run the Global asax sets up the container and sorts out all the modules by providing them with their config settings - the one I'm interested in at the moment is the NHibernate module - so this gets the connection string set into its constructor.

I want to build some tests to test Data Access with NHibernate - we've got repositories and a service layer but this isn't necessarily relevant.

Should I be adding an extra project to the Solution with all my tests in and if I do this do I need to replicate the database connection string in an autofac config for this test project and build a test container in this project which will test my data access?  Or should I be trying to get hold of the web app's container to do the testing with - I assume not as the Global.asax's Application_start will not run unless hit by an http GET.  I don't really want to replicate all the config and container creation of the web app but at the moment I'm thinking I will have to...?

Comment: Hmmm - saw a post that perhaps the container isn't even necessary and I can just setup these objects myself - but I'm still going to have to keep an identical config file to get hold of the connection string and other config data...

Comment: Update - I've made some progress here -not sure was the correct solution so let me know your thoughts: created a new project in my .sln called Testing.  Copied the config from the web.config into this project and called it Testing.config. Made alternative NHibernateModule called NHibernateTestModule so as not to use .HttpRequestScoped() - as HttpRequest will not exist for testing client.  Also copied the ContainerBuilder code from the global.asax into my test [Setup] method and then resolve the service layer in my test method from this container.  This all seems to have worked - thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to see the slow response to this. It isn't all that common to write integration tests for the actual DAL - much of the time unit tests against a stubbed DAL are sufficient - so there's probably not as much experience out there with this kind of scenario.

If you put all of your configuration into Autofac Modules, your Global.asax content could be as simple as calling `builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader())` - the same configuration file could then be loaded from your integration tests using the overload of `ConfigurationSettingsReader()` that takes a filename.

Rather than have a separate module for NHibernate under test, consider using `InstancePerLifetimeScope()` instead of `HttpRequestScoped()/InstancePerHttpRequest()`. This has the same effect (unless you've tinkered with the lifetime hierarchy :)) and will work in both web and non-web scenarios.

Hope this helps!
Nick